# How to set session timeout with spring boot embedded tomcat

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, session-timeout, jhipster

I don't manage to set session timeout in my Jhipster WebApp (spring boot  + Spring security + angularJS)

I just did the simplest way :

```
...
/**
 * Configuration of web application with Servlet 3.0 APIs.
 */
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
{
 ....
@Inject
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;
....
/**
     * Set up Mime types.
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container)
    {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        // IE issue, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/711
        mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        // CloudFoundry issue, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/64
        mappings.add("json", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        container.setSessionTimeout(serverProperties.getSession().getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        log.info("SessionTimeout = {}", serverProperties.getSession().getTimeout());
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/login"));
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }
...

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "server", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class ServerProperties
{
    private Session session = new Session();

    public static class Session
    {
        private int timeout = 6;

        public int getTimeout()
        {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(int timeout)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }

    }

    public Session getSession()
    {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(Session session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

Application.yml

```
server:
    port: 8080
    session:
      timeout: 1
```

Logs informs that the session in 1 minute length :

```
2016-07-28 16:17:03.103  INFO 6248 --- [  restartedMain] com.tess2i.config.WebConfigurer          : SessionTimeout = 1
```

After starting the WebApp, I logged in WebApp, Then I waited more than 1 minute. Then I click somewhere to query server. All was still working. No session error/redirection.

What else needs to be done ?

Comment: There was no need for your custom implementation - `server.session.timeout` property is used by default. Are you sure you're not using JWT authentication? Or have remember-me enabled?

Comment: According to the Documentation, the units of that property are in seconds.  server.session.timeout= # Session timeout in seconds.  http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't need to provide any custom implementation, setting `server.session.timeout` should be supported through Spring Boot out of the box, see [the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for more details.

As far as timeouts and redirects are concerned, are you sure you're not using remember-me or JWT authentication or other authentication methods that don't rely on HTTP sessions and their expiration?

Comment: Yes you're right, there is a remember-me authentication in jhispter. But I just added the token validity like this :  http.csrf().and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler()).authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                     .and().rememberMe()
                    .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices).rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenValiditySeconds(10).key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key")).and() . ..... but nothing change

Comment: Well, that is a different issue altogether and has nothing to do with the current question- could you open up another question for that scenario and provide a more detailed code sample? As for this question, I suggest you disable the remember me authentication and verify whether session timeout works.